# Android ListView smooth scroll loading images on disk

Tags: android

I have identified a problem making my listview scrolling jerky. I am loading images from disk while scrolling. Here's sample code:

```
private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyListItemExt> {
//...
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
//...        
                    Bitmap bit = SharedCode.sharedGetImageFromDiskOrInternet(thisAppContext, "contacts" + File.separator + data.image_file_name);                         
                    if (bit != null) {                                                                       
                      ViewTreeObserver vto = icon.getViewTreeObserver();
                      vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                        new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                          @Override
                          public void onGlobalLayout() {
                            icon.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);                                                                 
                            icon.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                            SharedCode.sharedUtilScaleImage(icon,false);                                
                          }
                        }                        
                      );                                                                       
                      icon.setImageBitmap(bit);                                                
                      icon.setBackgroundColor(data.backgroundColorInt);
                      icon.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
                      icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
```

Not sure if it would be wise to use async here... (And if so, the optimal way of doing it) It would be bad if the user scrolled on in main ui thread and **icon** reference was no longer valid.

This leaves another option of prefetching all images on startup, but I don't like to hold images in memory.

Is it possible to use an async construct that will load images in background and make them visible as they load if the user still has the iem visible in the listview? Any "best practise" at this? (I am still a rookie at Android)

Answer (score 2):

Image caches are a whole science, that is not worth doing yourself if youre a rookie and expect smooth bugfree performance.

Implement Google Volley library instead (theres been a nice IO talk this year too)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to give [AQuery](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading) a shot. It's working quite nicely for me.